# Nvim LSP dartls is unable to start

Tags: flutter, dart, neovim, nvim-lspconfig

I would like to configure a development environment for flutter, I just configured flutter and android studio and I already got a started app running. Now I just need to configure the [dartls](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#dartls), I've been playing around with the cmd property since it looks like the default configuration is not able to find the executable. Since flutter packages the dart-sdk along with it, I changed the path accordingly.

```lua
require'lspconfig'.dartls.setup{
    cmd = {"dart", "~/source/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/analysis_server.dart.snapshot", "--protocol=lsp"},
    on_attach = on_attach
}
```

Are you sure this is the right path?

```sh
ls ~/source/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/ | grep analysis_server
# analysis_server.dart.snapshot
```

Why did you change the --lsp flag?

```
dart ~/source/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/analysis_server.dart.snapshot --help | grep protocol
    --protocol=<protocol>                 Specify the protocol to use to communicate with the analysis server.
          [analyzer] (default)            Dart's analysis server protocol (https://dart.dev/go/analysis-server-protocol)
          [lsp]                           The Language Server Protocol (https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol)
```

Are you receiving any errors when opening a dart file?

```
Spawning language server with cmd: `dart` failed. The language server is either not installed, missing from PATH, or not executable.
```